# What's the difference between using the '==' comparator and using .contains('val') with spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook

I have a DataFrame created from joining three other dataframes together that I need to do many sum case statements to. I found the withcolumn() function may be my solution but when I do a comparison on a column that has a char I get two wildly different numbers when I use either .contains() or '=='.

The below code shows how both are being used-
Here is the code with .contains:

```
test_data.withColumn('NewCol', F.when((test_data.col1 == 'str') & ((test_data.col2.contains('X')) | (test_data.col2.contains('Y'))) ,1).otherwise(0)) \
                .groupBy('KEY') \
                .agg(F.sum('NewCol').alias('NewCol))
```

The resulting count of this is 127470 rows > 0

And here is the code with the comparator:

```
test_data.withColumn('NewCol', F.when((test_data.col1 == 'str') & ((test_data.col2 == 'X') | (test_data.col2 == 'Y')) ,1).otherwise(0)) \
                .groupBy('KEY') \
                .agg(F.sum('NewCol').alias('NewCol))
```

and the resulting count of this is 531645 rows > 0.

As you can see the number of rows that have a 1 is much larger when using the comparator vs .contains(). Is .contains() filtering before doing the comparison or is there something else causing the wildly different numbers?

Comment: `==` is an exact match of the entire column, `contains()` matches a substring.

Comment: Your parenthesis grouping is not the same in the two queries, that explains the big difference.

Comment: Can you edit or tell me where they are different? Because I do not see where the differ between the two. The two statements after the '&' are grouped together as the or only for them and the statement before the '&' is by itself. And all of those are grouped within the when statement where they should be. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: @Barmar That makes sense but I don't think it really solves my problem. The dataset I'm working with is hundreds of millions of entries and I have it limited to only one million for testing. The column that is being compared is a column that only contains a char. This column only has one of four possible characters so even though that's the case the resulting count should be the same shouldn't it?

Comment: Changing the parentheses changes the logic of the matching, because of the precedence of `&&` and `||`.

Comment: Never mind,  I misread the queries before. You have so many extra parentheses that make it hard to see where they match up.

Comment: I suggest you try it with a smaller dataset, like 100 rows, and look at the difference in results.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, I know its a tad confusing. But the codebase I'm translating over to python and Pyspark has a 350+ select sum(case when) statement that I'm trying to find a way of converting nicely and I just can't see a nice way besides the withColumn() I'll break down the dataset and see if I can find something. Thanks!

Comment: I'm just saying that you don't need the parentheses around `(test_data.col1 == 'str')` and `(test_data.col2.contains('X'))`

Comment: Use the parentheses that are important for grouping the `&` and `|` operators, but don't put parentheses around the individual comparisons.

Comment: You're right I can take those out. Thanks for pointing that out. I think I just had them in there for when I was testing between the two options I mentioned.

Comment: @DeveloperGuy I think you will need to provide a small [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples) for us to help you debug.

Answer (score 0):

== matches the entire string
.contains() search in to the string  looking for the string
Example:
"yesterday"== "day" is false
but
"yesterday".Contains("day") is true

Comment: This makes sense but it doesn't solve my problem, which may be my fault with how it's worded? But thank you for answering. The column that is being compared is a column that only contains a char. This column only has one of four possible characters so even though that's the case the resulting count should be the same shouldn't it? There is no string to compare against, just a single char.

Comment: This doesn't explain why a query that uses `==` returns *more* results than the query that uses the more permissive `contains()`.